# Entry module not found: Can't resolve './assets/app.js'

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to use webpack but i get an error

```
$ node_modules/.bin/webpack
Hash: d1aee5dc037997fae5a6
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Time: 31ms

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/app.js' in 'D:\template\src'
```

It's my first time using webpack.

here is my script

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: {
    app: './assets/app.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
};
```

My folder structure

[image]

I think i get the error here 
`context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),` I just don't know with what i replace that part.

I already read this `https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started` and already try searching with google about how to use webpack. Any solutions ?.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "buefy": "",
    "bulma": "",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`context`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context) option defines the base directory that is used to resolve anything in the webpack config. You are using `./src/` as the base directory, so `./assets/app.js` is resolved inside the `src` directory (it would technically be `./src/assets/app.js`).

If no `context` is provided, webpack will use the current directory, which is what you want. You can remove `context` entirely from your config. You probably also want to output the bundle into a directory such as `./dist` instead of into `./node_modules`. Your config would be as follows.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './assets/app.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
};
```

You were looking at the webpack 1 docs, but you should use the newer docs, which are significantly better: [Webpack - Getting Started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).